# Choose App Center or Application Insights for WinForms application

Tags: azure-application-insights, visual-studio-app-center

I have a Winforms application that is currently using Application Insights SDK to capture error logs, events, exceptions, form views, and another telemetry.
App Center now supports WinForms applications and it also supports exporting the telemetry into Application Insights. The question I have now is should I remove Application Insights SDK from my WinForms app and use AppCenter SDK instead? Are there any benefits of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be difficult to steer you one way or another without knowing your exact situation. As you have noted, either one will work. If you want a generic answer, App Center is the one designed for monitoring desktop apps.

I can do is give you some guidance on what things to consider when making your decision.

1. Both systems support custom metrics, however, the base set of metrics will diverge over time as App Insights is geared towards web apps whereas App Center is focused on Mobile and Desktop clients. If App Center offers baseline metrics that better suit your needs than it will be easier to maintain than custom metrics within App Insights.
2. The two systems have different pricing models. ([App Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/usage-estimated-costs)) ([App Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/general/pricing)). This means there may be a significant cost difference depending on how you leverage the service.
3. If you are using several different Azure services but would only use the monitoring in App Center, then it may be simpler to stick with App Insights. I would put more weight into items 1 and 2, but administration carries costs as well.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. We choose to stay with Application Insights.
1. Already using it and almost happy with the metrics it provides. Also, we extensively use custom events.
2. Because I wanted to export the data from AppCenter to Application Insights, I would end up paying for both services. Better to pay only for one.
3. Yes, we are using Application Insights for Web apps, REST APIs, Windows services, scheduled jobs.